# how to access through the matches in file-name completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In case of file-name completion, is there a way to access through the matches that get displayed after a double tab?

Answer (score 1):

Some shells support this. Some don't. Some only if you set a particular input mode.

Try tabbing more. If that doesn't do it, and you're using bash, try

```
bind -p > .inputrc
$EDITOR .inputrc
```

Look for the line that looks like

```
"\C-i": complete
```

and make it say

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

and then restart your shell. Now if you hit tab, rather than showing you a list of options, it should step through the available options. If you still want the list, you can try hitting the escape button twice (that command sequence should still be bound to `complete`).

If you're not using bash... try giving more information?